# What is the source of 'Ma'alin bekodesh'?

Tags: kedusha-holiness

Frequently, in halacha we see the rule of מעלין בקודש- loosely translated as "we go 'upwards' in holiness."

One example of this application is that one may use a parchment of tefillin to fix a Torah but not vice versa, because a Torah is considered 'holier' than tefillin.

Is there a Biblical verse for this principle? From where does this concept emanate?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[Menachot 99a](https://www.sefaria.org/Menachot_99a.10) derives this principle from two biblical sources.

**We don’t descend in holiness**: This is learned from the fact that after Moshe began to erect the Mishkan, no one else (of lesser holiness) was allowed to help him complete it ([Shemot 40:18](https://www.sefaria.org/Exodus.40.18)). [This is following one explanation of [Rashi](https://www.sefaria.org/Rashi_on_Menachot_99a.10.1) there; [Rashi](https://www.sefaria.org/Rashi_on_Menachot_99a.10.1) himself gives two other explanations.]

**We ascend in holiness**: This is learned from the fire-pans of Korach’s followers which were turned into a covering for the altar ([Bamidbar 17:3](https://www.sefaria.org/Numbers.17.3)).